# Extend use case as base case for the include use case

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

[image: Uml diagram]

The above use case diagram is to detect fall

So basically, I was trying to use the 'Alarming', 'send SMS' and 'stop SMS' use case as an extension from the base case 'detection of fall' but they also have include relationship as shown in the diagram. Therefore, I tried to do it as shown in the diagram above
Any comments, please? Is it correct?

Comment: This is not a use case diagram but a functional decomposition. The use case is `detect fail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel the obligation to indicate `if` conditions in a use-case diagram, it should probably not be a use-case diagram anymore. Try to represent this as an activity diagram, and simplify your use case to something as simple as  “Alert for situations of distress”.